# How do I use xml namespaces with find/findall in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I'm trying to parse content in an OpenOffice ODS spreadsheet. The ods format is essentially just a zipfile with a number of documents. The content of the spreadsheet is stored in 'content.xml'.

```
import zipfile
from lxml import etree

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('spreadsheet.ods')
root = etree.parse(zf.open('content.xml'))
```

The content of the spreadsheet is in a  cell:

```
table = root.find('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table')
```

We can also go straight for the rows:

```
rows = root.findall('.//{urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0}table-row')
```

The individual elements know about the namespaces:

```
>>> table.nsmap['table']
'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0'
```

How do I use the namespaces directly in find/findall?

The obvious solution does not work.

Trying to get the rows from the table:

```
>>> root.findall('.//table:table')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1792, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.findall (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:41770)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1297, in lxml.etree._Element.findall (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:37027)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 225, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 200, in iterfind
    selector = _build_path_iterator(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 184, in _build_path_iterator
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](_next, token))
KeyError: ':'
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Python API for OpenOffice to process the spreadsheets?

Comment: Hi I am using etree.QName to access Elements and attributes with Namespace. its a neaty way with the help of a dictionary of namespaces, and it works with find and findall method also. for more information please refer to:  http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If `root.nsmap` contains the `table` namespace prefix then you could:

```
root.xpath('.//table:table', namespaces=root.nsmap)
```

`findall(path)` accepts `{namespace}name` syntax instead of `namespace:name`. Therefore `path` should be preprocessed using namespace dictionary to the `{namespace}name` form before passing it to `findall()`.

Comment: Interesting, but there seems to be a lower-level problem: table.xpath('.//table:table-row', nsmap=table.nsmap)
*** XPathResultError: Unknown return type: dict

Comment: @saffsd: Note: *namespaces=* not *nsmap=*. Try: `root.xpath('.//table:table-row', namespaces={'table': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0'})`

Comment: As an aside, if the xml properly defines namespaces, `root.nsmap` should automatically be populated with the namespaces within the document. This is a solid solution.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe the first thing to notice is that the namespaces
are defined at *Element level*, not *Document level.*

Most often though, all namespaces are declared in the document's
root element (`office:document-content` here), which saves us parsing it all to collect inner `xmlns` scopes.

Then an element nsmap includes :

- a default namespace, with `None` prefix (not always)
- all ancestors namespaces, unless overridden.

If, as ChrisR mentionned, the default namespace is not supported,
you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to filter it out
in a more compact expression.

You have a slightly different syntax for xpath and
[ElementPath](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath).

---

So here's the code you could use to get all your first table's rows
(tested with: `lxml=3.4.2`) :

```
import zipfile
from lxml import etree

# Open and parse the document
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('spreadsheet.ods')
tree = etree.parse(zf.open('content.xml'))

# Get the root element
root = tree.getroot()

# get its namespace map, excluding default namespace
nsmap = {k:v for k,v in root.nsmap.iteritems() if k}

# use defined prefixes to access elements
table = tree.find('.//table:table', nsmap)
rows = table.findall('table:table-row', nsmap)

# or, if xpath is needed:
table = tree.xpath('//table:table', namespaces=nsmap)[0]
rows = table.xpath('table:table-row', namespaces=nsmap)
```

Comment: If you need a nsmap that includes the default namespace, use (Python 3): `nsmap = {k if k is not None else 'default':v for k,v in root.nsmap.items()}`

Comment: For Python 3 rename iteritems() above to just items().

Comment: One can also do `nsmap = root.nsmap;
    nsmap.pop(None)`, which might be slightly more clear.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to get all the namespaces in the XML document (and supposing there's no prefix conflict).

I use this when parsing XML documents where I do know in advance what the namespace URLs are, and only the prefix.

```
        doc = etree.XML(XML_string)

        # Getting all the name spaces.
        nsmap = {}
        for ns in doc.xpath('//namespace::*'):
            if ns[0]: # Removes the None namespace, neither needed nor supported.
                nsmap[ns[0]] = ns[1]
        doc.xpath('//prefix:element', namespaces=nsmap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Etree won't find namespaced elements if there are no `xmlns` definitions in the XML file. For instance:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xml_doc = '<ns:root><ns:child></ns:child></ns:root>'

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_doc)

# finds nothing:
tree.find('.//ns:root', {'ns': 'foo'})
tree.find('.//{foo}root', {'ns': 'foo'})
tree.find('.//ns:root')
tree.find('.//ns:root')
```

Sometimes that is the data you are given. So, what can you do when there is no namespace?

My solution: add one.

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xml_doc = '<ns:root><ns:child></ns:child></ns:root>'
xml_doc_with_ns = '<ROOT xmlns:ns="foo">%s</ROOT>' % xml_doc

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_doc_with_ns)

# finds what you're looking for:
tree.find('.//{foo}root')
```