# XPath with lxml failing

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to query with XPath an html document parsed with lxml. The document is a straight html-only download of the page about [Plastic in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic). Then I parse it with lxml disabling entity substitution to avoid an error with '&reg'

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse("plastic.html",etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False))
```

Then, I retrieve the namespace url

```
htmltag = root.iter().next()
nsurl = htmltag.nsmap.values()[0]
```

Now, I would like to use xpath queries on either 'root' or 'htmltag', but I am unable to do so. I have tried different ways, but the following seems to me the most correct form, which yields errors anyway.

```
root.xpath('//ns:body',namespace={'ns',nsurl})
```

And this is what I get

```
XPathResultError: Unknown return type: dict
```

I am running the commands in an IPython console, but I don't think that might be the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is `root.xpath('//ns:body',namespaces={'ns':nsurl})
`

Comment: also take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210730/how-do-i-use-xml-namespaces-with-find-findall-in-lxml

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a simple miss spell. You should use `namespaces` instead of `namespace`.