# Extract value from element when second namespace is used in lxml

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

I am able to extract values from elements (using lxml in python 2.7) when one namespace is used. However I can't figure out how to extract values when a second namespace is used. I want to extract the value within `//cc-cpl:MainClosedCaption/Id` but I keep getting `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression` errors. 
To be specific, the value I'm trying to exract from my sample xml is `urn:uuid:6ca58b51-9116-4131-8652-feaed20dca0d`

Here's a snipped of the xml (from a Digital Cinema Package):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompositionPlaylist xmlns="http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CPL-20040511#">
    <Reel>
      <Id>urn:uuid:58cf368f-ed30-40d8-9258-dd7572035b69</Id>
        <MainPicture>
          <Id>urn:uuid:afe91f7a-6451-4b9f-be2e-345f9a28da6d</Id>
        </MainPicture>
        <cc-cpl:MainClosedCaption xmlns:cc-cpl="http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CC-CPL-20070926#">
          <Id>urn:uuid:6ca58b51-9116-4131-8652-feaed20dca0d</Id>
        </cc-cpl:MainClosedCaption>
    </Reel>
</CompositionPlaylist>
```

Here  is an example of code that works:

```
from lxml import etree
cpl_parse = etree.parse('filename.xml')
pkl_namespace = cpl_parse.xpath('namespace-uri(.)') 
xmluuid =  cpl_parse.xpath('//ns:MainPicture/ns:Id',namespaces={'ns': pkl_namespace})
for i in xmluuid:
    print i.text
```

When I try to specify the following xpath instead: `//ns:MainClosedCaption/ns:Id` - I end up with errors.

When I specify the namespace with:
    `pkl_namespace = 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CC-CPL-20070926#"'`

I receive a `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression` error

I know this is a stupid attempt, but the following produced the same error:
`'//ns:cc-cpl:MainClosed Caption/ns:cc-cpl:Id'`

I tried to include the two namespaces in a dictionary as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36227869/2188572 , and while I don't get any errors, I end up with no values extracted.
Here's my dictionary:

```
namespaces = {
    'ns': 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CPL-20040511#',
    'ns2': 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CC-CPL-20070926#',
}
```

and my command:

```
xmluuid =  cpl_parse.xpath('//ns:AssetList/ns2:MainClosedCaption/ns2:Id',namespaces=namespaces)
```

I found this,  [Extracting nested namespace from a xml using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113552/extracting-nested-namespace-from-a-xml-using-lxml) which is actually the exact same kind of xml that I'm working on, but his request was to get the namespace URL, not the actual values of elements.

Edit:
Using the method from the previous answer to extract the namespace, I tried the following, but got the same errors:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]

cpl_parse = etree.parse(filename)
pkl_namespace = etree.QName(cpl_parse.find('.//{*}MainClosedCaption')).namespace
print pkl_namespace
xmluuid =  cpl_parse.xpath('//ns:cc-cpl:MainClosedCaption/ns:cc-cpl:Id',namespaces={'ns': pkl_namespace})
for i in xmluuid:
    print i.text
```

and here's the errors in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sub.py", line 8, in <module>
    xmluuid =  cpl_parse.xpath('//ns:cc-cpl:MainClosedCaption/ns:cc-cpl:Id',namespaces={'ns': pkl_namespace})
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2115, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57654)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 370, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:146564)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 238, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144962)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 224, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144817)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Id` element in MainClosedCaption belongs to the 2004 namespace. Only an attribute `xmlns="..."` can change the default namespace; attributes of the form `xmlns:something="..."` only add a namespace which has to be explicitly declared.

Try this:

```
from lxml import etree
cpl_parse = etree.parse('filename.xml')
xmluuid = cpl_parse.xpath('//proto2007:MainClosedCaption/proto2004:Id', namespaces={
    'proto2004': 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CPL-20040511#',
    'proto2007': 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-CC-CPL-20070926#',
})
for i in xmluuid:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: Success!! Thank you so much. I think I was roughly on the right track with my ns1/ns2 attempt, but my general confusion and lack of knowledge led me astray.

Comment: Yes I believe you were very close. To avoid namespace confusion I'd recommend using useful labels (I don't know if proto is the best). Namespaces called `ns1` to `ns999` are for machines - but they like to name their variables `var1` to `var999`.

Comment: You're correct. I probably saw the `ns:` in a stack overflow example and just stuck with it.