# lxml searching for tags when namespaces are present

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I'm a little confused about navigating an xml document that has namespaces with `lxml.etree`. I've seen a few threads  on this topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210730/how-do-i-use-xml-namespaces-with-find-findall-in-lxml), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree#)) as well as the [lxml docs](https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-do-namespaces-work-in-lxml) but still haven't figured out the answer.

```
xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2" level="2" metaid="metaid_0000001" version="1">
    <model id="Teusink2000_Glycolysis" metaid="metaid_0000002" name="Teusink2000_Glycolysis">
        <annotation>
        </annotation>
    </model>
</sbml>"""
from lxml import etree
utf8_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
xml = etree.fromstring(xml.encode('utf-8'), parser=utf8_parser)
```

Searching for the root element doesn't seem to work, but I guess thats because its the root element and therefore you don't really need to search for it

```
print(xml.nsmap)
print(xml.findall('sbml'))
print(xml.findall('sbml', namespaces=xml.nsmap))
print(xml.findall('sbml', namespaces={'': 'http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2'}))
```

produces

```
{None: 'http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2'}
[]
[]
[]
```

Searching for the `model` element however, does work provided you give it a namespace

```
print(xml.findall('model'))
print(xml.findall('model', namespaces=xml.nsmap))
print(xml.findall('model', namespaces={'': 'http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2'}))
```

produces

```
[]
[<Element {http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2}model at 0x2125d7c0888>]
[<Element {http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2}model at 0x2125d7c0448>]
```

But, searching for the `annotation` element does not work as I expect.

```
print(xml.findall('annotation'))
print(xml.findall('annotation', namespaces=xml.nsmap))
print(xml.findall('annotation', namespaces={'': 'http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2'}))
```

produces

```
[]
[]
[]
```

Could anybody point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You can only search for the current level using `annotation`. If you want to search the whole tree, you need to use `print(xml.findall('.//annotation', namespaces=xml.nsmap))`.

```
print(xml.findall('.//annotation', namespaces=xml.nsmap))
# [<Element {http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2}annotation at 0x7fbcb9a14308>]
```